# Rollback integration with aws code pipeline which is deploying a React app on S3

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-codepipeline

I have a code pipeline in AWS which performers CI/CD for my react app and deploy it into the s3 bucket.

Now I am curious how can I achieve a rollback in this flow.

my current code pipeline flow is:

git bucket(repo) - > Code build(to build the app into static hosting) - > code deploy action(with action  provider s3).

In case anything goes wrong, how can I achieve a rollback into this CI/CD pipeline?

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? CodeDeploy can't deploy to S3, only to EC2/ECS and Lambda.

Comment: My action is "deploy" which deploys on S3, not the code deploy application.

Comment: @Marcin Could you please help me with this :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387705/how-lambda-function-and-api-gateway-handle-disaster-recovery?noredirect=1#comment113855414_64387705

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CodePipeline (CP) does not have build-in mechanism for rollbacks. Thus in your case I see **three options**:

- if the target S3 bucket is **versioned**, you can roll back "manually" by deleting latest version of each object. This way you will effectively move back to a previous deployed version of your application.
- You have to roll back on your **bitbucket** in a same way you would reverse last PR or commit. The change in bitbucket should trigger your CP to do new deployment, but of old version from the git repository.
- The other option, could involve your **CodeBuild** to do a backup of your currently deployed files in the bucket while building new version of the app. This way each run of CP would also create a backup of an existing version to other bucket. Then the roll-back would be as simple as just copying files from one bucket to the other.